# ¿Cómo puedo comparar listas de listas y eliminar duplicados en Python?

Tags: python, lista

```
a = [
  ['azteca7.com', '3456704', 'azteca7.com - Azteca-7 - NOTICIAS - Despues-de-Todo - divBoxBanner', '300x250', 'CO', '1', '0', '0.42', '1', '100','0.4', '1'],
  ['azteca7.com', '3456704', 'azteca7.com - Azteca-7 - NOTICIAS - Despues-de-Todo - divBoxBanner', '300x250', 'CO', '1', '0', '0.42', '1', '100','3', '3']
]
```

Tengo una lista de listas donde quiero averiguar si son iguales hasta el penúltimo elemento, dejando fuera el 1 y el 3 en este caso.
Como podemos ver en este caso son exatamente iguales y lo que quiero es que de ser así, deje la que tenga el menor valor ultimo, obteniendo:

```
a =[
  ['azteca7.com', '3456704', 'azteca7.com - Azteca-7 - NOTICIAS - Despues-de-Todo - divBoxBanner', '300x250', 'CO', '1', '0', '0.42', '1', '100','0.4', '1']
]
```

Editada:

Si tengo más de dos items en la lista de listas, como puedo hacer?

```
d = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 2, 4, 2, 5]]
if d[0][:-1] == d[1][:-1]:  # si esta sublista es igual
    if d[0][-1] > d[1][-1]:  # el último elemento es mayor en la 1.ª lista
        d.remove(d[1])  # por tanto, eliminamos la 2.ª lista
    else:
        d.remove(d[0])

print d
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una lista de listas y quieres validar si la primera es igual a la segunda quitando el último (¿y penúltimo?) elemento.

Simplificando, si tenemos:

```
d = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
]
```

Entonces obtenemos todos los elementos de la primera lista, menos el último, diciendo:

```
>>> d[0][:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

O todos menos los dos últimos con:

```
>>> d[0][:-2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Luego es cuestión de comparar estas sublistas:

```
if d[0][:-1] == d[1][:-1]:  # si esta sublista es igual
    if d[0][-1] < d[1][-1]:  # el último elemento es menor en la 1.ª lista
         d.remove(d[1])  # por tanto, eliminamos la 2.ª lista
    else:
         d.remove(d[0])  # en caso contrario, eliminamos la 1.ª lista
```

En mi ejemplo, el resultado sería:

```
>>> d
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

---

Ahora bien, en los comentarios vimos que lo que tienes es algo un poco más complejo: una serie de listas que quieres agrupar teniendo en cuenta todos los elementos menos el último; una vez hecho eso, elegir la lista cuyo último valor sea menor.

Para ello debemos utilizar una forma de hacer más genérica y se me ocurre así:

- crea un diccionario cuyos índices son todas las posibles listas "capadas", es decir, sin el último elemento.
- recorre luego todas las listas y coge el menor último valor para cada tipo de listas. Guarda el valor en ese diccionario.

En código:

```
listas = {tuple(x[:-1]): x for x in datos}
for elemento in datos:
    indice = elemento[:-1]
    listas[tuple(indice)][-1] = min(indice[-1], listas[tuple(indice)][-1])
```

Y el resultado lo tienes en:

```
listas.values()
```

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> datos = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 8], [5, 6, 6]]
>>> listas = {tuple(x[:-1]): x for x in datos}
>>> listas
{(1, 2): [1, 2, 2], (7, 8): [7, 8, 8], (5, 6): [5, 6, 6]}
>>> for elemento in datos:
     indice = elemento[:-1]
     listas[tuple(indice)][-1] = min(indice[-1], listas[tuple(indice)][-1])
>>> listas
{(1, 2): [1, 2, 2], (7, 8): [7, 8, 8], (5, 6): [5, 6, 6]}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pero hay algo que modificar muy importante, mi lista de listas tiene más de 1000 elementos. Como podría hacer?

Comment: @MartinBouhier intenta proporcionar un [mcve] para ver más claramente el detalle, pero básicamente: ¿se trata de 1000 elementos, todos los cuales difieren en apenas el último elemento?

Comment: la acabo de editar, a lo que me refiero es que si la lista tiene mas de dos elementos como puedo hacer para que compare todos? Porque usando d[0][:1] y d[1][:1] me quedan fuera los elementos d[2][:1], d[3][:1] y así sucesivamente

Comment: @MartinBouhier claro, claro, entiendo. Lo que pasa es que no queda claro exactamente qué datos tienes. Fíjate que en tu pregunta mencionas que todos los elementos son iguales menos el último, cuando el penúltimo tampoco lo es. Además, lo que comentaba antes: ¿estos 1000 elementos son del mismo tipo, es decir, todos iguales menos el último? ¿o van agrupados de alguna otra forma? Clarifica esto por favor y revisito mi respuesta ;-)

Comment: Soy malo para hacer preguntas claras disculpa. El tema es asi, necesito revisar cada lista de la lista de listas, primero revisaría la lista d[0][:1] comparandola con d[1][:1], d[2][:1], d[3][:1] y si se repite en alguna comparar su último elemento e imprimir o almacenar en una nueva lista la lista que tenga el menor ultimo elemento. Luego analizaría la lista d[1][:1] y así hasta terminar. Me explico?

Comment: @MartinBouhier ¿pero cuál es el resultado final que buscas? ¿Pretendes obtener una lista de las listas con mayor último elemento? Simplifiquemos el caso: si tienes `[[1,2,3], [1,2,5], [8,9,10], [8,9,11]]`, ¿qué resultado deberías obtener?

Comment: En el caso que propones sería mi output: `[[1,2,3], [8,9,10]]`

Comment: @MartinBouhier de acuerdo, entendí. Eso sí, entiendo que debería ser `[[1,2,5], [8,9,11]]`, es decir 5 y 11 en lugar de 3 y 10 ¿no? Por eso de coger el mayor elemento en la última posición.

Comment: Necesito el menor pero es lo mismo, doy vuelta el signo! Gracias

Comment: @MartinBouhier añadí una versión genérica que contempla este caso. Revísala a ver si cumple lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tengo este error: `NameError: name 'indice' is not defined`

Comment: @MartinBouhier cierto, me dejé algo al transcribir la solución. Editado